# Entypo icon visible on design time, disappears in runtime

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to include entypo icons in my program and I see them in design time, but when I run program they disappear. This draws one icon:

```
        <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" >
            <Rectangle.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="Red" />
            </Rectangle.Resources>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cupcake}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

and app.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Entypo.ttf and Icons.xaml are set to build as Resource.

What am I missing?

PS: appbar_cupcake is part of Mahapps.Metro Resources, pulled from NuGet

```
<Canvas Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0" x:Key="appbar_cupcake">
        <Path Width="24" Height="25" Canvas.Left="13" Canvas.Top="11" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 32,14C 33.1046,14 34,14.8954 34,16C 34,16.3643 33.9026,16.7058 33.7324,17L 34,17C 35.1046,17 36,17.8954 36,19C 36,20.1046 35.1046,21 34,21L 35,21C 36.1046,21 37,21.8954 37,23C 37,24.1046 36.1046,25 35,25L 15,25C 13.8954,25 13,24.1046 13,23C 13,21.8954 13.8954,21 15,21L 16,21C 14.8954,21 14,20.1046 14,19C 14,17.8954 14.8954,17 16,17L 16.2676,17C 16.0974,16.7058 16,16.3643 16,16C 16,14.8954 16.8954,14 18,14C 19,14 21,12 25,11C 29,14 31,14 32,14 Z M 15,26L 35,26L 32,36L 18,36L 15,26 Z " />
    </Canvas>
```

I also tried adding to the top of Icons.xaml:

```
<Color x:Key="BlackColor">#000000</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="{DynamicResource BlackColor}" />
```

Comment: Post xaml code for resource `appbar_cupcake`.

Comment: If you hard code Fill like this in resource itself `Fill="Black"`. Does it show at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the build action for Icons.xaml to Page instead of Resource.